# Angularfire2 email authentication referencing variables outside of promise

Tags: authentication, typescript, angular, promise, angularfire

I have this component:

```js
export class LoginComponent {
  login_error = "";

  constructor(public af: AngularFire) {
    this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => console.log(auth));
  }

  login(credentials) {
      this.af.auth.login({ email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password})
      .catch(function (error) {
        switch (error.code) {
          case "INVALID_USER":
            console.log("Invalid email");
            this.login_error = "Email is invalid"; //<----- broken
            break;

          case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
            console.log("Invalid password");
            this.login_error = "Password is invalid"; //<----- broken
            break;

          default:
            break;   
        }
      });
  }

  logout(){
    this.af.auth.logout();
  }
}
```

I want to be able to set the login_error variable (within the .catch) which is used in the template to inform the user that either their email or password is incorrect, but I cannot reference variables outside of the Promise. Is there something I am doing wrong or is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an arrow function instead. So you will be able to use the contextual `this` (the component instance here):

```
login(credentials) {
  this.af.auth.login({ email: credentials.email, password: credentials.password})
  .catch((error) => { // <-------
    switch (error.code) {
      case "INVALID_USER":
        console.log("Invalid email");
        this.login_error = "Email is invalid";
        break;

      case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
        console.log("Invalid password");
        this.login_error = "Password is invalid";
        break;

      default:
        break;   
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I laughed when I saw how simple the solution was. This indeed worked. I definitely have more to learn about ES6 and JS. Thank you Thierry!